# Topmenu disappeared in some pages (Magento)

Tags: php, magento

TopMenu does not appear in the pages of client administration (my requests, my account, etc ...). But on the other pages, will be normal.

I write:

echo $this->getHtml('level-top')

And pages appear normal, but in the pages of client administration not.

PS: Sorry for english. Translate of Google haushauh :)

Comment: it will be better if you share your site link.

Answer (score 0):

The customer pages do have an own layout file called `customer.xml` in your theme. Please check whether the block 'level-top' or it's parents are deleted.